# How can I defeat the dragon's challenge in Candy box 2? (Hell)

Tags: candy-box-2

So the question is, how do I defeat the challenge from the dragon? The hell with the devil.
I thought I'd have to use Anti Gravity + Jump to get over those 2 lava holes, but when I want to jump this "bat" or what ever is placing mobs on my head, so I can't jump.
Any tutorials?
Thanks in advance.